# Neo4j how to query to get a subgraph?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

We have a graph of a few million nodes. All the nodes in the  graph have a relationship with one of three date nodes. Date1:2022, Date2:2021, Date3:2020. I want to work with the nodes connected to Date2 for example. But my queries, complicated as they are, get very hard to handle if in every single line I match I have to add a where clause with the dates. I was wondering if I can work with something like this:

`match (d:date)<-[]-(n) where d.date=2020 with n`

and then continue with the rest of the query. Here is an example of a query:

```
match (d:date)-[:dated]-(s_0:shirt)-[:priced]-(s:stock) 
where s.value=1 and d.date=2021
with collect distinct(s_0) as s_0_l
match (d:date)-[:dated]-(s_1:shirt)-[:priced]-(s:stock) 
where s.value=2 and d.date=2021
with collect distinct(s_1) as s_1_l,s_0_l

unwind [x in s_1_l where ( x in s_0_l)] as double_stocked_list

return doule_stocked_list limit 200
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem? Can you share your query?

Comment: I added a query in the question. I hope it helps.

Comment: It's hard to help when the query you shown doesn't work at all. You use s variable in both WHERE clauses, but there is not s variable defined.

Comment: I thought it's there in (s:stock). And it has the property value.

Answer (score 0):

you could work with the first query:

"`match (d:date)<-[]-(n) where d.date=2020 with n`"

by adding:
"`match path = (d:date)<-[]-(n) where d.date=2020 with n`"

and then use path after

Comment: Is holding the path instead of the nodes cheaper in terms of memory/speed for some reason?

Comment: not sure this is just easier